# Can I have multiple Powershell Consoles in one window?

Tags: windows, powershell

So, now I have many open apps, often 3-4 powershell consoles. I'm able to order the powershell windows to watch them together (top left, top right, bottom left, bottom right).

So this means that if I switch to another app, when I switch back I have to restore all multiple powershell windows to see them all again.

What I want is, to create only one 'shared window' for many powershell, because when I need one, I need all of them to see.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can do this in VSCode if you've PS setup as a terminal: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_managing-multiple-terminals

Comment: @JamesC. Yes this is a way to solve it, but I hope there are more, because sometime VSCode crash (and I have to restart all services), and which is the bigger problem with it, I like to see the powershells and VSCode together on different screens (I have 3 monitor) to better overview.

But so far this is the only way, thank you! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ConEmu has this option.

You can also configure it to open as much consoles as you want when it starts.

[image]

[ConEmu website](https://conemu.github.io/)

Enjoy!

Answer (score 16):

Just to add more details about Windows Terminal approach:

1. Open a Windows Terminal
2. Type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> to open a new Pane in the same tab
3. Type <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to close the current Pane

[image]

If you need more details or modify the settings, go to next page [Panes in Windows Terminal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/panes)

Answer (score 3):

VSCode can have [Multiple Terminals](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_managing-multiple-terminals) which is the closest to this I've seen, quoted from documentaion:

> You can create multiple terminals open to different locations and easily navigate between them. Terminal instances can be added by hitting the plus icon on the top-right of the TERMINAL panel or by triggering the **Ctrl+Shift+`** command. This creates another entry in the dropdown list that can be used to switch between them.
>
> [image]
>
> You can also split the terminal by triggering the Ctrl+\ command or via the right click context menu
>
> [image]

Answer (score 2):

Windows now provides the Windows Terminal.
Windows Terminal can split the terminal into panes and can also run different shells (i.e. cmd, powershell, and bash through the wsl)

You can install Windows Terminal directly from the Windows Store.

Answer (score 0):

Create a virtual machine where you can run your PowerShell sessions uninterrupted. The PowerShell windows are always where I placed them when I come back.

It could be an expensive solution depending on your needs, but I have been doing this a long time. It's a robust solution since the only user processes on the VM are my PowerShell sessions.

[image]